# MVC - Controller default

Tags: php, yii

I mainly use Kohana and Yii, but my question is addressed to the mvc pattern in general.

The Route class, in general, call the appropriate controller as a unique resource through the url. If it is missing, it invokes the default controller.

The point is this: my default page (site.com /) is to login. Once logged on does not make sense to show the login page, and returning to site.com I would like it to invoke another controller.

The possible solutions I found are: to redirect to another page, if logged. Or use HMVC. But I asked myself if there are appropriate strategies.

Have you ever been faced with a situation like this? How did you solve?

Answer (score 1):

Default controller can check, if user is logged or not, and if not - call kind of `LoginController`, without redirecting.
And I think it's not best Usability design, when user should login, before he could see the site.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off having an "admin dashboard" type controller as your default one, and do a check to see if the user is logged in or not.

If they aren't logged in, redirect to the `login` controller, and if they are logged in, proceed as normal.

That would make better sense to me; at least.